# Conversion of R example of 'binary encoding by hashing the cardinalities' to Python code

Tags: python, r, encoding, binary, data-science

I found this great blog article about categorical, numeric, one-hot and binary encoding @ [Laurae’s Data Science & Design curated posts](https://medium.com/data-design/visiting-categorical-features-and-encoding-in-decision-trees-53400fa65931)

However, the most interesting part I'd like to try is written in R:

```
my_data <- c("Louise",
         "Gabriel",
         "Emma",
         "Adam",
         "Alice",
         "Raphael",
         "Chloe",
         "Louis",
         "Jeanne",
         "Arthur")
matrix(
  as.integer(intToBits(as.integer(as.factor(my_data)))),
  ncol = 32,
  nrow = length(my_data),
  byrow = TRUE
)[, 1:ceiling(log(length(unique(my_data)) + 1)/log(2))]
```

Any help on how to apply this in Python on 'category' columns of a Pandas Dataframe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Categoricals are a pandas data type, which correspond to categorical variables in statistics: a variable, which can take on only a limited, and usually fixed, number of possible values (categories; levels in R), You can use the [documentation of pandas](http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/categorical.html), a small example from the documentation:

```
In [1]: s = pd.Series(["a","b","c","a"], dtype="category")

In [2]: s
Out[2]: 
0    a
1    b
2    c
3    a
dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [a, b, c]
```

or as you asked for in DataFrame:

```
In [3]: df = pd.DataFrame({"A":["a","b","c","a"]})

In [4]: df["B"] = df["A"].astype('category')

In [5]: df
Out[5]: 
   A  B
0  a  a
1  b  b
2  c  c
3  a  a
```

Differences to R’s factor:

The following differences to R’s factor functions can be observed:

> R’s levels are named categories
>
> R’s levels are always of type string, while categories in pandas can be of any dtype.
>
> It’s not possible to specify labels at creation time. Use s.cat.rename_categories(new_labels) afterwards.
>
> In contrast to R’s factor function, using categorical data as the sole input to create a new categorical series will not remove unused categories but create a new categorical series which is equal to the passed in one!
>
> R allows for missing values to be included in its levels (pandas’ categories). Pandas does not allow NaN categories, but missing values can still be in the values.